# Http, how do you deal with non text response in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get an array buffer from an http request that is explicitely said to be an array buffer. However I didn't manage to do that and the doc on the subject is rather scarce.

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': "audio/mpeg"});
let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer, headers: headers });
this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/piano/A4.mp3")
         .subscribe((response)=> this.play(response));
```

But I can't manage to get the array buffer out of the response. The response body in the console is inintelligible so I assume it must be the correct format. Also the content type of the response is indeed "audio/mpeg".

**Edit** : Here is some working code for future readers

```
play(arrBf) {
     this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrBf, (buffer) => {
      let source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource(); 
      source.buffer = buffer;                   
      source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);       
      source.start(0);                          
     });
  }

  loadSounds(){
    let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer});
    this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/piano/A4.mp3", options)
      .map(r => r.arrayBuffer())
      .subscribe((d)=> { this.play(d)});
  }
```

and define the audio context in the constructor or smtg :

```
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    let AudioContext_ = AudioContext || webkitAudioContext;
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext_();
  }
```

Comment: have you tried without the brackets `new Blob(response.blob(), {type: 'audio/mpeg'})` ?

Comment: But if you do response.blob(), why do you put it in a `new Blob` call? Perhaps you can use the `response.arrayBuffer()` to initiate the blob

Comment: Let me formulate that into an answer :)

Comment: what does your component and play function look like?

Comment: @PierreDuc it was a typo I'll post it anyway for future readers

Comment: @PierreDuc to be more precise if you notice in the first piece of code, I forgot the options in the get method. It took me more time than I'd like to admit to notice it.

Comment: Looking good! Nice to see you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some working code for future readers

```
play(arrBf) {
     this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrBf, (buffer) => {
      let source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource(); 
      source.buffer = buffer;                   
      source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);       
      source.start(0);                          
     });
  }

  loadSounds(){
    let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer});
    this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/piano/A4.mp3", options)
      .map(r => r.arrayBuffer())
      .subscribe((d)=> { this.play(d)});
  }
```

and define the audio context in the constructor or smtg :

```
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    let AudioContext_ = AudioContext || webkitAudioContext;
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext_();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a `Blob` from a `Response` object in Angular2 you can use the `arrayBuffer()` method:

```
let blob: Blob = new Blob([response.arrayBuffer()], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
```

Documentation from angular is not updated yet though

Comment: As I answered you above `response.arrayBuffer();` does the trick to transform the response to the array buffer yeah. In my specific case there is actually no need to transform to a blob. Unfortunately I still can't play the sound as for some reason it cannot decode the data. But that's another question I guess :)